# Provisioning MySQL remote users

Tags: mysql

Seeking advise on optimal way to provision remote MySQL user permissions, when the source of connections is a large network block.

Since the MySQL server may have DNS lookups disabled for performance reasons, I do not believe provisioning by the hostname is possible. Am I correct on this?

What is the best way to provision a large network block of remote users to access a given instance? I am familiar with adding a % in the IP address, but this could potentially give access to IPs outside the allowed network mask.

Consider: `192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.30`, which would be `/27`. `192.168.0.%` would give access to IPs that should not be provisioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both questions are easily answerable in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html).

For your first question you are correct.  If you turn lookups off, then you can't grant access based on those lookups that won't happen.  This is clearly documented in the documentation for the directive that disables the lookups [skip-name-resolve](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve).

For your second question, the ideal way would be for you to specify the subnet.  The page [Specifying Account Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-names.html) details how to do this.  `'username'@'192.168.0.0/255.255.255.224'` is a perfectly valid account definition.

Using wildcards for the hostname should be avoided, especially when dealing with IP address ranges.  In your consider example.. '192.168.0.%' not only matches everything under 192.168.0.0/24, it also matches 192.168.0.example.com.. 192.168.0.example.net.. etc.